# Node.js Passport get Facebook session on Page Load

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, passport.js

I've got the passport `Facebook Strategy` working fine. However, reading `facebook` documentation I stumble upon this :

**FACEBOOK DOCS**

> A special consideration when using the Query String setting:
>
> If you would like to use the server-side authentication flow with App
>   Center it is important to make sure you are passing the redirect_uri
>   parameter correctly when exchanging your code for an access token. You
>   should set your redirect_uri parameter to the click-through URL to
>   your site. In most cases the URL will look something like:
>
> http://www.example.com/?fb_appcenter=1&fb_source=search&code=CODE_HERE
>   thus you should set your redirect_uri to the same value. Please make
>   sure that this logic is dynamic as the query parameters appended to
>   your click-through URL may be subject to change.

On the App Center there is a `visit website` button that sends users to the app and in the process logs them in.
How can I do this with passport? Do I have to add the query string to the `callbackURL`?
I'm guessing it's the same problem, but I'd also need something like the `FB.getLoginStatus()` provided by facebook javascript SDK to link users if they have their facebook open and previously added the app.
Is all this provided by `passport` in any way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the callback for facebook-pasport be dynamically constructed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513427/can-the-callback-for-facebook-pasport-be-dynamically-constructed)