# Node.js - Facebook Logging in a user from the App Center (Visit website button)

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

I'm using `Passport` and `Facebook Strategy` for authentication. It works fine from within my website. Clicking the *login button* makes a get request to `auth/facebook/` and I succesfully log in the user.
 I have the same url in the app details:

[image: Facebook login website]

However the App Center `Visit Website` button adds this to the query:

```
{ fb_source: 'appcenter',
  fb_appcenter: '1',
  code:xxxxx...., // this is what i want
}
```

And upon clicking i get this error:

> "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

What i don't get is that this works AT THE SAME time on my website. How do I handle this extra parameters and log in the user upon clicking on the *visit website* button?

I also posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149896/node-js-passport-get-facebook-session-on-page-load). I've been dealing with this for a while now and can't get my head around it...

note:
As far as I know, it is required for app approval that the `Visit Button` authenticates the user upon clicking and doesn't prompt them with another login message.

Comment: I partially fixed this by removing the query parameters from the request. Issue still remain, how do I handle these extra parameter?