# Invoke redirect_uri in passport-github2 (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

Using `passport-github2` to sign in users with their Github email. Implemented `/auth/github` and `/auth/github/callback` as per example:

```
router.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github', {
  scope: [ 'user:email' ]
}));

router.get('/auth/github/callback',
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Works fine.

Next step is to use `redirect_uri` so that unauthenticated users landing on pages that require authentication are actually redirected there after completing the authentication flow. Thinking along the lines of authenticating users with `?redirect_uri=.../auth/github/callback?[landed_at]` so that I can change the `res.redirect('/');` line in the callback handler accordingly.

Can't seem to find the right way to pass the redirect_uri parameter to `passport` so I get it right back on the `callback` call. Not sure if I am seeing this properly.

Answer (score 1):

Dug [a bit deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513427/can-the-callback-for-facebook-pasport-be-dynamically-constructed) and found it, posting solution for reference:

First, when redirecting for authentication, add the original URL as a query parameter so it can be pushed further. Base64 encoding always helps.

```
// authentication middleware
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) { // or choose your own way of passing auth info
    return next();
  }

  // not authenticated, redirect to oauth flow
  var redirect_uri = new Buffer(req.originalUrl);
  res.redirect('/auth/github?redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri.toString('base64'));
});
```

Then, pass the parameter into the authenticator on the callback URL:

```
router.get('/auth/github', function (req, res, next) {
  var callbackURL = '/auth/github/callback';
  if (req.query.redirect_uri) {
    callbackURL += '?redirect_uri=' + req.query.redirect_uri;
  }
  passport.authenticate('github', {
    scope: [ 'user:email' ],
    callbackURL: callbackURL
  })(req,res,next);
});
```

Finally, use the parameter in the callback handler:

```
router.get('/auth/github/callback', function (req, res, next) {
  var redirect_uri = '/';
  if (req.query.redirect_uri) {
    // prepend host to avoid open redirects
    redirect_uri = config.HOST + '/' +
                   new Buffer(req.query.redirect_uri, 'base64').toString();
  }
  passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    successRedirect: redirect_uri
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Note the Base64 decoding in the callback, counterpart to the encoding in the auth middleware.