# how to redirect a user to complete the registration process after social signup with the data obtained from those socials, [passport,node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport.js

Being new to the world of node.js for a couple of months now,  I still find somethings challenging. Please how do I redirect redirect a user to complete his registration with the data obtained using social signup like Facebook or Google, I am using passport and right now  I've not been to figure out how to achieve that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the public auth has a field like "redirecr_url" to redirect to with authentication token in the request in order to finish up third party logic.

You can redirect to one of your app's page and write routes logic to finish anything you want

Comment: here is a related post using Facebook as an example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513427/can-the-callback-for-facebook-pasport-be-dynamically-constructed